# How to pause handler for some time when another handler is running?

Tags: android, handler

I'm developing an application. In the application I'm using two handlers.

Based on my program, both the handlers run simultaneously.

But the problem is when the both  handlers run simultaneously the UI is hanging for some time.

My intention is when one handler is running to pause the other handler for some time.

If any one know the solution please help me.